# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (9121, 14) instead

Tags: python, arrays, keras

I was running these lines of code:

```py
import tensorflow
import keras
from keras.utils import np_utils
import pickle

# Get the data into the correct format for Keras 
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

# One hot encode the target 
lb = LabelEncoder()
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_train))
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_test))

print(X_train.shape)
print(lb.classes_)
#print(y_train[0:10])
#print(y_test[0:10])

# Pickle the lb object for future use 
filename = 'labels'
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(lb,outfile)
outfile.close()
```

And I'm getting this error:
[image]

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 1-d array of labels in LabelEncoder.
LabelEncoder is for 1D data with the shape (n_samples,))